# IIS Giving Error "An unexpected error has occurred" on one server but works fine on other servers for all SP Sites

Tags: sharepoint-server, iis

I am getting this error on all my sites on one server only. I am using Sharepoint 2010. I did try IIS reset but no luck. I need urgent solution to solve this problem as I have been looking for the solution for many days and now the deadline is very near. Any help would be appreciated, thanks
[image]

Comment: Are the application pool started? Check the IIS logs to see what you can find. As well as the SharePoint logs on the server, using ULS to try to see what's going on.

Comment: Hi Christoffer, Yes I did check application pool and everything working fine. I get an exception in SharePoint Tracing (Logs) and the error is "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The handle is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070006 (E_HANDLE))" and I cannot find any working solution for this

Comment: I can be because .net is missing an assembly reference. Try re-registering it: aspnet_regiis.exe -i